# How to compress and decompress between C++ and Java?

Tags: java, c++, inflate, compression

all

I faced a problem to compress and decompress between java and C++.

Here is Java code runs at server.

```
public static byte[] CompressByDeflater(byte[] toCompress) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream compressedStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DeflaterOutputStream inflater = new DeflaterOutputStream(compressedStream);
    inflater.write(toCompress, 0, toCompress.length);
    inflater.close();

    return compressedStream.toByteArray();
}

public static byte[] DecompressByInflater(byte[] toDecompress) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream uncompressedStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayInputStream compressedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(toDecompress);
    InflaterInputStream inflater = new InflaterInputStream(compressedStream);

    int c;
    while ((c = inflater.read()) != -1)
    {
        uncompressedStream.write(c);
    }

    return uncompressedStream.toByteArray();
}
```

And I receive a binary file from server.

Then I have to decompress it using C++.

Where do I start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compression program uses zlib (see [JDK documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html)), so you need to use a C++ zlib library to decompress its output.

The [zlib documentation](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) is the place to start.

Comment: I find using the `uncompress` or `uncompress2` functions in `zlib.h` makes things easier in C++, which wraps a lot of the more detailed work, see here: https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h